# How do I make a col-6 col-6 grid system without bootstrap?

Tags: css, layout, grid

How do I make a row with 2 columns that becomes 2 rows with one column each using just CSS and no frontend frameworks? I tried reading up on CSS Grid but it seems too confusing for me. Would appreciate if someone can simply it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Not really via CSS, but you can use `<table>`

Answer (score 3):

try this code for example no bootstrap needed

```
 .row::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }
    [class*="col-"] {
        float: left;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Comment: let me know if it was usefull

Comment: good luck with your project ✔

Comment: There should add "* { box-sizing: border-box;}". Otherwise the col will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row; 
} 
.flex-col{
 padding: 15px;
 margin: 0 15px;
 background: #ddd;
 }
 .flex-row-multicolum{ 
   display: flex; 
   flex-direction: row; 
   flex-wrap: wrap; 
   flex-flow: row wrap; 
}
.flex-row-multicolum .flex-col{ width: 40%; margin: 0 15px 15px}
```

```html
<h4>1 Row with two colum</h4>
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">Colum 1</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Colum two</div>
</div>

<h4>1 Row with four colum</h4>
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-col">Colum 1</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Colum two</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Colum three</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Colum four</div>
</div>

<h4>2 Row with two colum</h4>
<div class="flex-row-multicolum">
  <div class="flex-col">Colum 1</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Colum two</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Colum three</div>
  <div class="flex-col">Colum four</div>
</div>
```